# Crear una variable global en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, variables-globales

Me gustaría crear una variable global en laravel para poder utilizarla en controllers como en vistas; me gusatria hacer esto sin tener que usar `Session` o la `Cache`. Existe algun mecanismo colegas? Investigando me percate que en `AppServiceProvider` puedo crear una como esta que cree:

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
            $view->with('is_lock', LockSession::isLocked());
        });
```

Esta variable que cree sirve solamente para las vistas o me sirve tambien para llamarla en mis controllers

Comment: que clase de dato vas a guardar en esas variables globales? estos datos nunca van a cambiar?

Comment: quiero almacenar un arreglo que almacene cualquier dato para utilizarlo en otro lugar despues

Comment: y entiendo que este arreglo va a cambiar constantemente?

Comment: este arreglo solamente va a variar para ser vaciado

Comment: Estoy programando un bloqueo de sesion de usuario y necesito almacenar algunas datos en una variable y no quiero usar el Session o la Cache

Comment: Cuál es el inconveniente con usar Session o la Cache ?

Comment: que llega el momento en que uso la funcion de bloquear y el navegador me dice este error:

Esta página no funciona
La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.
Borrar las cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Limpie las cookies y nada

Comment: Si te redirige demasiadas veces es por que entro al ciclo y lo que esta mal ahí es la lógica, seguramente no te has dado cuenta pero sin duda es la lógica de bloqueo -> redireccionamiento -> nuevamente a la página pero como esta bloqueado entonces -> redireccionamiento, etc... la cache no te funciona si lo haces con sesiones por que las sesiones están del lado del servidor. saludos.

Comment: Estuve revisando y la logica esta correcta lo que da el error cuando va a realizar la funcion redirect